# Query with INNER JOIN return empty result

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have these two tables:

Contact

```
id | datetime   | book_id | name         |
1    2018-04-16     1        foo   
2    2018-04-16     1        another foo
3    2018-04-16     1        foo2
4    2018-03-01     1        foo3
```

Details

```
id  | datetime | book_id |  
 1   2018-04-16    1
```

I want select al the records that have as `datetime` 2018-04-16 and as `book_id` 1, so the result must be:

```
1    2018-04-16     1        foo   
2    2018-04-16     1        another foo
3    2018-04-16     1        foo2
4    2018-03-01     1        foo3
1   2018-04-16      1
```

my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM Contact
         INNER JOIN Details
         ON Contact.book_id = Details.book_id
         WHERE Contact.book_id = :book_id AND 
         Contact.datetime BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
```

the query return no rows, why I did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried hard coding in the values instead of passing them in?  i.e. `Contact.book_id = 1` instead of `Contact.book_id = :book_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates presumably have time components.  So, try converting the value to a date before using `between`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contact c INNER JOIN
     Details d
     ON c.book_id = d.book_id
WHERE c.book_id = :book_id AND 
      DATE(c.datetime) BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date;
```

Comment: I just discored that if I increment end date by one day I get the records, so I guess is a time problem?

Comment: The problem is that the example data you've shown is not the same data that is actually stored in your database.

Comment: @Magheggio . . . Yes, if you increment `end_date`, that would indicate that the time component is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a single date  you should use = not between  for between you need a range

```
SELECT * FROM Contact
INNER JOIN Details  ON Contact.book_id = Details.book_id
 WHERE Contact.book_id = 1  
         Contact.datetime = '2018-04-16'
```

or use a valid range  (eg just for test)

```
SELECT * FROM Contact
INNER JOIN Details  ON Contact.book_id = Details.book_id
 WHERE Contact.book_id = 1  
         Contact.datetime  between   '2018-04-15'   and  '2018-04-17'
```